# ROC curve error in randomForest

Tags: r, random-forest, roc

I am trying to create a ROC curve off the below. I get an error that states Error in prediction(bc_rf_predict_prob, bc_test$Class) : 
  Number of cross-validation runs must be equal for predictions and labels.

```
library(mlbench) #has the Breast Cancer dataset in it
library(caret)
data(BreastCancer) #two class model

bc_changed<-BreastCancer[2:11] #removes variables not to be used


#Create train and test/holdout samples (works fine)
set.seed(59)
bc_rand <- bc_changed[order(runif(699)), ] #699 observations
bc_rand <- sample(1:699, 499) 
bc_train <- bc_changed[ bc_rand,]
bc_test  <- bc_changed[-bc_rand,]

#random forest decision tree (works fine)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
set.seed(59) 
bc_rf <- randomForest(Class ~.,data=bc_train, ntree=500,na.action = na.omit, importance=TRUE)

#ROC
library(ROCR)
actual <- bc_test$Class 
bc_rf_predict_prob<-predict(bc_rf, type="prob", bc_test) 
bc.pred = prediction(bc_rf_predict_prob,bc_test$Class) #not work- error
```

Error-Error in prediction(bc_rf_predict_prob, bc_test$Class) : 
  Number of cross-validation runs must be equal for predictions and labels.

I think it is coming from the fact when I do the:

```
bc_rf_predict_prob<-predict(bc_rf, type="prob", bc_test)
```

I get a matrix as the result with two columns Benign and a list of its probabilities and a second column of Malignant and its list of probabilities. My logic tells me I should only have a vector of probabilities.

Comment: Have you tried using `str(predict(bc_rf, type="prob", bc_test))` to determine data type / structure of `predict`?

Comment: agree that is where the problem might be. I get matrix [1:200, 1:2] 1 0.12 1 1 0 1 1 1 0.05 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:200] "3" "4" "5" "12" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "benign" "malignant"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "matrix" "votes"

Comment: So- what do I do on the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [page 9 of the ROCR Library documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROCR/ROCR.pdf), the `prediction` function has two required inputs, `predictions` and `labels`, which must have the same dimensions.

In the case of a matrix or data frame, all cross-validation runs must have the same length.

Since `str(bc_rf_predict_prob) > [1] matrix [1:200, 1:2]`, this means `str(bc_test$Class)` should have a matching dimension.

It sounds like you only want the first column vector of `bc_rf_predict_prob`, but I can't be certain without looking at the data.

Comment: thank you. Needed to add [,2] to the end of bc_rf_predict_prob. Hence bc_rf_predict_prob[,2].